# Need help for int args (threads)

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, args

I'm trying to edit this code to work with ints parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <string.h> 


void* worker (void* param) {
      int* nr = (int *) param;
  printf ("I got: %d\n",nr);
}

int main (int argc, int *argv[])
{
  pthread_t th;
  int i;  
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
      pthread_create (&th, NULL, worker,(void*)argv[i]);
      pthread_join (th, NULL);
  }
}
```

This is not working, smth about pointers, I don't understand. Can anyone explain me? I don't want to use "atoi" function.
For number 5 and 2 I get: -1078000975,-1078000973  and a warning:

> 11:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
>      printf ("I got: %d\n", nr);
>      ^

Comment: `int nr = *(int *)param`

Comment: the code is overlaying the value in 'th' for every thread created, so the pthread_join will only see the last thread created, not all the threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. `argv` should be written `char * argv[]`, not `int * argv[]`.
2. Your `(void *)` cast in your `pthread_create()` call is unnecessary.
3. Your thread function should return a `void *`.
4. `atoi()`, or its more capable cousin, `strtol()`, is *exactly* what you're looking for, here. You can either use them, or convert your strings manually, which is suboptimal.

Here's a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 

void * worker (void * param)
{
    char * numstr = param, * endptr;

    long num = strtol(numstr, &endptr, 0);
    if ( *endptr ) {
        printf("Invalid number.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("I got: %ld\n", num);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t th;
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
        pthread_create (&th, NULL, worker, argv[i]);
        pthread_join (th, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and some sample output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./trd 5 haha 10
I got: 5
Invalid number.
I got: 10
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments you recieve are smaller than 10, you can do this:

`pthread_create (&th, NULL, worker,(void*)(argv[i][0]-'0'));`

This can be done because ASCII numbers begin at 48 ('0' value). So if you receive a '7' (55 ascii number), you can subtract the '0' to get it: 55-48=7.
If the arguments can be 10 or greater, you must use atoi or a self-implementation of that function, as you can not cast from char* to int in C.

There is another problem with your code, you try to print an int*, which is only a variable that contains a memory address. You should recieve it as an int:

```
void* worker (void* param)
{
  int nr = (int) param;
  printf ("I got: %d\n",nr);
}
```

EDIT:
So your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <string.h> 


void* worker (void* param) {
      int nr = (int) param;
  printf ("I got: %d\n",nr);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t th;
  int i;  
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
      pthread_create (&th, NULL, worker,(void*)(argv[i][0]-'0'));
      pthread_join (th, NULL);
  }
}
```

It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the pointer to the string and then manipulate it.

```
pthread_create (&th, NULL, worker, argv[i]);   //cast is not required

void* worker (void* param) {
      char* nr = param ;
```

Now you got your string in the thread. Get the first character, and convert it to an integer.

```
    int n = nr[0]-'0' ;
    printf ("I got: %d\n",n);
}
```

Comment: @AlbertoSotoBallesteros Right, I forgot to convert.

Comment: the suggested code needs to loop through the string, until seeing either a '\0' or the current char fails isdigit() otherwise only the first digit will be handled.  And before adding each successive digit to the result to be printed 'n' needs to be multiplied by 10 to make room for the next digit